# sending different output using same logstash file

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, logstash

I need my logstash conf file to send a message to a kafka topic to indicate that the document processed has been sent to elasticsearch. I have my logstash file ready to structure the data to send to the ElasticSearch but I need to post 'yes' or 'no' message to a kafka topic through the same logstash file.

Comment: Can you explain *why* you want to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mutiple outputs like

```
output 
    { 
        #output to console
        stdout { 
            codec => rubydebug 
               } 

        #output to elasticsearch    
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => [ "192.168.1.245:9201" ]
                      }

        #output to kafka          
        kafka {
            codec => json
            topic_id => "mytopic"
              }   

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to have the yes/no value in a field, let's call it value.

Then add a kafka output, with the plain codec using the format option to add the yes/no value:

```
output {

  #rest of your output configuration

  kafka {
    ...
    codec => plain {format => "%{[value]}"}
  }
}
```